# Conditional Assignment in Julia

Tags: julia

In R, I can conditionally assign values like this:

```
A = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol = 2)
A = 
1  3
2  4

A[,1][A[,2] == 3] = 1000

A =
1000  3
   2  4
```

In Julia, this same format doesn't work.

```
A = [1 3; 2 4]
A =
1  3
2  4

A[:,1][A[:,2] .== 3] = 1000

A =
1  3
2  4
```

I can't seem to figure out what's going on. Can anyone help?

Edit: Thanks. This works for replacing one value with another, like 1 with 1000. But it will not replace multiple. Why is that?

```
>A = [1 3 5; 2 4 6]
>A
1  3  5
2  4  6

>A1 = sub(A, :, 1)
>A1
1
2

>A2 = sub(A, :, 2)
>A2
3
4

>A1[A2 .> 2] = 1000
1000

>A
1000   3   5
   2   4   6
```

Why does the replacement stop with the first instance and not continue to the second?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Julia: Assignment in Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757047/julia-assignment-in-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the linked post, range indexing produces copies.  This can be circumvented using `SubArray`

```
julia> A = [1 3 5; 2 4 6]
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  5
 2  4  6

julia> A1 = sub(A, :, 1)
2-element SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},2}:
 1
 2

julia> A2 = sub(A, :, 2)
2-element SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},2}:
 3
 4

julia> A1[A2 .== 3] = 1000
1000

julia> A
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1000  3  5
    2  4  6
```

Or using a `for` loop

```
julia> for i = 1:size(A,1)
       A[i,2] == 3 && (A[i,1]=1000)
       end
```

Edit: It seems the odd behavior you are seeing has been fixed at some point.  Here's what I get on the latest git master

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+4743
Commit dc088f7 (2015-05-08 13:29 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-redhat-linux)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3

julia> A = [1 3 5; 2 4 6]
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3  5
 2  4  6

julia> A1 = sub(A, :, 1)
2-element SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},2}:
 1
 2

julia> A2 = sub(A, :, 2)
2-element SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},2}:
 3
 4

julia> A2 .> 2
2-element BitArray{1}:
 true
 true

julia> A1[A2 .> 2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> A1[A2 .> 2] = 1000
1000

julia> A1
2-element SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,2},Tuple{Colon,Int64},2}:
 1000
 1000

julia> A
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1000  3  5
 1000  4  6
```

In general, the `for` loop version will be faster than doing things this way